# Get all the possible combinations I can play on a 6/49 lottery

Tags: php, for-loop

The idea is to get all the possible combinations I can play on a 6/49 lottery.
For the first 2 numbers it works. When, I add the conditions for the third number it says:  `Undefined variable: b`. I don't understand why. I use echo there to check if the program is working.

Here is the code.

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<50 ; $i++)
{
    $a=$i;
    for ($j=1 ; $j<50 ; $j++)
    {
        if ($i!=$j)
        {
            $b=$j;  
        }
        for ($k=1 ; $k<50 ; $k++)
        {

            if ($k!=$j && $k!=$i)
            {
                $c=$k;
                echo "$a $b $c<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell us what language. Fix formatting.

Comment: It might be a shell script, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first iteration `$i == $j`, so `$b` is never initialized. You can fix it by extending the `if` to cover the inner loops:

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<50 ; $i++)
{

  $a=$i;
  for ($j=1 ; $j<50 ; $j++)
  {

    if ($i!=$j)
    {
        $b=$j;

      for ($k=1 ; $k<50 ; $k++)

      {

        if ($k!=$j && $k!=$i)
        {
            $c=$k;
            echo "$a $b $c<br>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$b is undefined when $i == $j. I suppose you only want to run the inner for loop when $i != $j. Note that this problem is typically solved with a function recursion (then you don't need to hard-code the 6 numbers).

Hope that helps,

- Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 6 nested for loops....

I don't get the language you are using, so i will put it in some pseudo code...

```
for (a=1; x<50-5; a++){
  for (b=a+1; x<50-4; b++){
    for (c=b+1; x<50-3; c++){
      for (d=c+1; x<50-2; d++){
        for (e=d+1; x<50-1; e++){
          for (f=e+1; x<50; f++){
            print (a,b,c,d,e,f);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```